# What is the oldest known depiction of Isis with wings?

Tags: ancient-egypt, archaeology

Some of the oldest known references to the goddess Isis are inscriptions, like the Pyramid texts.
However, I have been interested in the visual depictions of the Egyptian gods and how they change throughout the millennia.

[The oldest sourced image of winged Isis I have been able to find is from the tomb of Ramses III.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rameses_III_censing_and_libating_(KV11).jpg)

Wikipedia's section on the iconography of Isis says that Isis is usually depicted with wings when the image represents her protecting the dead. However, I have been unable to get a hold of the book referenced as a source, so I don't know how far that practice dates back. (The book is "The origins of Osiris and his cult" by J. Gwyn Griffiths)

In summary, I would like to know if there is a depiction of Isis with wings, older than the one in the tomb of Ramses III?

Comment: For one earlier example see here: http://ccivcopy.site.wesleyan.edu/project-7-2/new-kingdom-winged-isis-depictions-tomb-of-seti-i-and-tomb-of-horemheb/